# Unable to retrieve managed bean property through javascript call

Tags: javascript, jsf

Iam trying to retrieve a property value from a managed bean through my JSF facelet Javascript call like below but i dont get the value from my managed bean.

My managed bean has been set isPreviewScreen = false with getters and setters too.
Can someone help ?

Both the alerts doesnt give me a value in the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function #{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}verifyStatus(data){
  alert("#{contactBean.isPreviewScreen}");
  if (data.isPreviewScreen){
    alert(data.isPreviewScreen);
     $("##{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}previewScreenHeaderAlert").dialog();
  }else{
     $("##{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}previewScreenHeaderArea").show();
   }
};
</script>
```

Here is my content inside form:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{contactBean.loadPreviewScreenContents}">
                                <h:outputText title="#{crs.dateTime}" value="#{crs.dateTime}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" type="date" />

                                </h:outputText>
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{contactBean.crs}" value="#{crs}" />
                                <f:ajax render=":form1:previewScreenHeader" onevent="#{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}verifyStatus"/>

                            </h:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `data.isPreviewScreen` to `#{data.isPreviewScreen}` like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function #{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}verifyStatus(data){
  alert("#{contactBean.isPreviewScreen}");
  if (#{data.isPreviewScreen}){
    alert(#{data.isPreviewScreen});
     $("##{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}previewScreenHeaderAlert").dialog();
  }else{
     $("##{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}previewScreenHeaderArea").show();
   }
};
</script>
```

Comment: nopes.. this is incorrect ... it rips off all jquery fucntionalities inside .. i have tried the same by retrieving bean property from bean and it worked:

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That is incorrect... it rips off all jQuery functionalities inside. I have tried the same by retrieving bean property from bean and it worked:

```
function #{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}verifyStatus(data){
  if ("#{contactBean.previewScreen}"==false){
  $("##{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}previewScreenHeaderAlert").dialog();
  }else{
$("##{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}previewScreenHeaderArea").show();
  }
};
```